# How can I write to the response stream without throwing an exception

Tags: asp.net-core, server-sent-events

I'm implementing SSE by writing data to the response stream in asp.net core.

This initially goes well, but after the first message has been sent, `writeAsync` on the HTTP response throws an exception:

IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'

How do I prevent premature disposal of this object so that I can keep writing to it?

Answer (score 0):

In an asynchronous route method, the response is no longer valid when the task returned by the method completes. Make sure not to complete that task before you finish writing to the response.